# Delete Request with params MongoDB NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I try to send delete request from Angular 4 to mongoDb

I have an array of ids, which I want to delete and in my service I have a function

```
  deleteData(id) {
    return this.http.delete( this.api, id)
  }
```

Then in my component I build an array of objects (because I need to pass it to backend as JSON - as an array it won't be probably recognised)

```
  deleteData(data) {
    const dataToSend = [];
    let oneDataToSend;

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      oneDataToSend = {'_id': ''};
      oneDataToSend._id = data[i];
      dataToSend.push(oneDataToSend);
    }
    this.service.deleteData(dataToSend).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

And after that I try to delete objects, which ids are the same as in a query

```
app.delete('/tasks', function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body);
  var ids = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < req.body.length; i ++) {
    ids.push(req.body[i]._id);
  }
  var myquery = { _id: { $in: ids } };
  Model.collection.deleteMany(myquery, function(err, obj) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});
```

Here I got the problem, that there req.body is empty {}
Also, in console in Network section I see 2 requests 
OPTIONS (with Status Code 204 No Content)
DELETE without any info

Could you please give me a hint and help to solve this problem?

Comment: Show the output of `console.log(data)` as you are passing into your `deleteData()` method. It's almost certainly not what you think it is, and even so your composition/decomposition on both ends is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see the OPTIONS request with a 204 NO CONTENT response is because of [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) (CORS). The client is checking if it is allowed to make a DELETE request to your backend.

Consider allowing CORS in the backend application. For an easy way for express, use [expressjs/cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors). However, make sure you understand the security implications of allowing cross-site requests.

Also, are you parsing the request body? If not, it will be undefined in req.body.

You can use [express.json()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json), it will attempt to parse the JSON of the request body and save it to req.body, but only if the header "Content-Type: application/json" is sent along with the request:

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.json()); // Parses request body if type is json. Saves to req.body.
```